# Rebuild node access permissions

Tags: 8, console

How can I rebuild the node access permissions?

`drupal node:access:rebuild` returns the following error message.

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] There are no commands defined in the "node:access" namespace.

I am using Drupal Console 0.11.3 and Drupal 8.2.0-rc2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're having issues with Drupal Console, you don't have access to it, or you're not using Drush, you can also do it via the UI.

- Login as an administrator
- Visit */admin/reports/status* (also located via the menu at *Reports->Status report*
- Find the *Node access permissions* section
- Click on the *Rebuild Permissions* link (which is also located on */admin/reports/status/rebuild*)

Comment: Worth mentioning that when doing this from the UI it can get quite a lengthy process when having a huge amount of nodes. PHP settings may need to be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 17):

With Drush:

`drush php-eval 'node_access_rebuild();'`

With Drupal Console:

`drupal node:access:rebuild`

Comment: +1 for Drush, -1 for posting the exact command OP posted in their question.

Comment: Worth mentioning that when you have quite lots of nodes you better batch the process like so: `drush php-eval 'node_access_rebuild($batch_mode = TRUE)'`.

Comment: Would be useful you'd link the docs as well: [`node_access_rebuild()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access_rebuild/8.2.x)

Answer (score 1):

For those people for whom running node_access_rebuild function using drush is not working.

I'm not very familiar with drush internals, but the code `drush php-eval 'node_access_rebuild();'` won't trigger batch processing. At least on the next drupal/drush versions (9.2.8, 10.6.1).

The thing is `node_access_rebuild` function do not call batch processing immediaetly.

What worked for me is writing drush script to call batch processing explicitly:

```php
<?php
// filename: rebuildPermissions.drush.php
// usage: drush scr ./rebuildPermissions.drush.php
// based on topic https://www.drupal.org/node/873132
node_access_rebuild($batch_mode = TRUE);

$batch =& batch_get();
$batch['progressive'] = FALSE;
drush_backend_batch_process();
```

and then just run it: `drush scr rebuildPermissions.drush.php`

But in the end of the day I've used [node_access_rebuild_progressive](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_access_rebuild_progressive) module for my needs and rebuilt 12K rules for 92K nodes in 5 minutes using drush.