# Restful permission is required

Tags: plugins

I've created a @RestResource plugin to provide a REST endpoint to get some data, but when I try a GET from Postman it shows this error:

> {
>       "message": "The 'restful get ez_share_document_resource' permission is required."
>   }

I thought it was because I need to add something else, so I decided to enable the Watchdog database log REST resource to prove it, but I got the same error:

> "message": "The 'restful get dblog' permission is required."

Rest module has set bc_entity_resource_permissions  as false.

This is the annotation of the plugin.

```
/**
 * Provides a resource to get view modes by entity and bundle.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "ez_share_document_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Ez share document resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/ezshare/{ezshare_id}"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class EzShareDocumentResource extends ResourceBase {
```

And this is my get method:

```
public function get($ezshare_id = NULL) {
    if ($ezshare_id) {
      $record = ['It Works!!'];
      if (!empty($record)) {
        return new ResourceResponse($record, 200);
      }

      throw new NotFoundHttpException($this->t('EzShare doc with ID @id was not found', ['@id' => $ezshare_id]));
    }

    throw new BadRequestHttpException($this->t('No EzShare doc ID was provided'));
  }
```

Drupal core is recently updated to 8.8.1.

Comment: You have to add the permission to the roles that must have the permission under, `/admin/people/permissions`.

Comment: Yes, all permissions are enabled for Authenticated users.

Comment: Do you use `cookie` or 'simple_auth' as authentication?

Comment: Yes, I use Basic Auth, but when I use cookies in the browser it works. The issue is only with Basic Auth.

Comment: You have to send the Authorization header with in Postman. In postman you can choose to authenticate with basic auth where you enter the username and password.

Comment: Yes, I have it, I'm using my user credentials, should I enable another permission? Headers are Content-type => application/json, Accept => application/json and Authorization => Basic aX....

Comment: If authenticated users have permission and you have configured postman to use basic auth, the only thing that I can think of as a problem is that either the username or password that you use is incorrect.

Comment: I thought the same, but I tested those from a different browser and they work. I was able to log in. I enabled the resource from REST UI like so: Ez share document resource /ezshare/{ezshare_id}: GET, PUT 
methods: GET
formats: json
authentication: basic_auth

Comment: Also I tested it with Soap UI and I got the same error, so it is not related with Postman. I dont know what else I should check

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I was able to solve this issue adding the method *permission* to the RestResource plugin like so:

```
public function permissions() {
  return [];
}
```

Comment: Yes! this is the right answer. Also you should add the annotation to your method like this:
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function permissions() {
    // permissions are required.
    return [];
  }

Answer (score 1):

The default permissions() method creates a permission per method

In ResourceBase

```
/**
* Implements ResourceInterface::permissions().
*
* Every plugin operation method gets its own user permission. Example:
* "restful delete entity:node" with the title "Access DELETE on Node
* resource".
*/
```

Shown in *admin/people/permissions*

[image: Permissions page entry]

Everything else being equal anonymous can be given access (or a specific role).

Clearing permissions doesn't open access.

Check the REST configuration. Either via configuration synchronisation or REST UI. Install the Rest UI module and check that an authentication provider is installed (OP Basic Auth). The permissions can be configured from the Rest UI interface

[image: Rest UI configuration]

Some authentication methods also require access. Check in the network monitor in the browser. With JWT for example, a request for an expired token is required first. If this is denied, or fails it is a problem with the authentication provider.

Comment: It's not so clear with JWT token, can you provide more info ? I'm testing with Postmant, but no matter what I write in the Bearer, I keep getting access to the endpoint.

Comment: I guess you turn off all access to make sure you are hitting the right end point? If there is full access without a token then it is an access rules problem, not a token problem.

Comment: Alright, but which access rule ? I haven't done anything specific, it's seems like a cache problem in my case because once it's validated I never go into the EventSubscriber provided by the JWT module

Comment: You could try rebuilding permission  /admin/reports/status/rebuild https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216940/rebuild-node-access-permissions